# Debugging Partial file aka net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: api, curl, digital-ocean

I have a [Dockerized service](https://github.com/kaihendry/greptweet/) so theoretically they should be exactly the same across my two servers. The only difference is production is running on Digital Ocean with CoreOS stable (835.9.0) and the dev is running from my home server under Archlinux.

Problem I noticed that when my API returns a lot of results, on production the request seems to be cut short resulting in the infamous **net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING** in the browser. I can reproduce [this issue](https://github.com/kaihendry/greptweet/issues/55) like so:

`curl -i 'http://greptweet.com/u/kaihendry/grep.php?q=http' >/dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 41274    0 41274    0     0  17846      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 17852
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining`

However is works fine on my home server:

```
curl -i 'http://gt.dabase.com/u/kaihendry/grep.php?q=http' >/dev/null
```

I am waiting to hear back from Digital Ocean. Is there anything else I might have missed? Content length? Compression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually in my error log if I cared to look closely:

```
[crit] 14#0: *3888 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi/2/03/0000000032" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client:...
```

The fix was [chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx](https://serverfault.com/a/703582/7798).

This [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/514044/nginx-is-cutting-the-end-of-dynamic-pages-and-cache-it) is also related.